# Sockets - Simultaneous UDP sockets

Tags: sockets

How many simultaneous UDP sockets could be opened? I am trying to connect multiple clients to a threaded-pool server and each client is bound to a particular port and address. As long as I am within 100 client connections,  I get no problem, but when I try beyond that I keep getting "Error too many open files" error at the client side for some clients. I tried setting fd-max in the config file and ulimit -n to 4096, but they are of no use in fixing this.

Comment: Are you creating them on the same port? UDP is connectionless, so you only need one UDP socket opened on the client side, and one on the server side.

Comment: There seem to be plenty of threads around the web dealing with similar problems. Just google the error string.

Comment: Why are the clients bound to specific ports? It isn't necessary.